# How to configure Wordpress as headless CMS with Next.js

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, graphql, next.js, wordpress-rest-api

I have a `WordPress` application in `htdocs` folder in Xampp and a separated Next.js application running in `localhost:3000`.

Usually WordPress takes a theme installed and you can navigate the site at `http://yourdomain.com`. On the other hand the admin UI can be accessed from `http://yourdomain.com/wp-admin`.

My question is the following, how can I replace the `twentytwentyone` theme with my Next.js application that uses `GraphQL` to request data from WordPress endpoint and make it as a root path, in other words `http://yourdomain.com` must load the Next.js application but also `http://yourdomain.com/wp-admin` must be the WordPress admin UI. (Without a theme).

If this isn't the ideal thing to do, and both WordPress and Next.js application should be deployed separately, how can I use WordPress only for admin UI and cancel any other rendering that's coming from WordPress, like the default page that uses `twentytwentyone` theme and make WordPress only as an API endpoint ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have completed a similar thing.
The easiest way I found to achieve this was to install wordpress on a subdomain.

```
http://admin.yourdomain.com
```

I then ran the next application on

```
http://yourdomain.com
```

This way your next application can pull information from the wordpress API at `http://admin.yourdomain.com`
and you can redirect the home page of the wordpress application to `http://admin.yourdomain.com` to `http://admin.yourdomain.com/wp-admin`

This means anyone accessing the wordpress site will be automatically redirected to the admin login, whilst the wordpress API can function normally.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, I will try this asap.. Thanks again :)